# Scroll top, then bottom, then top, then bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an auto scroller. It should slowly scroll to bottom, and then should slowly scroll to top, and so....

I have written this,

```
$(".scrollballer").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 12000);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.scrollballer').animate({scrollTop:0}, 12000); 
},12000);

setInterval(function(){

$(".scrollballer").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 12000);

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.scrollballer').animate({scrollTop:0}, 12000); 
},12000);

},12000);
```

However, it scrolls faster when scrolling from top to bottom. How to make it same speed?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle to show your problem ? I can't see why it would scroll faster from top to bottom from just this code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the `setInterval` is set for `12000`, but it takes `24000` to get back up to the top, so the `setInterval` should be at `24000`.

```
setInterval(function() {

    $(".scrollballer").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 12000);

    setTimeout(function() {
       $('.scrollballer').animate({scrollTop:0}, 12000); 
    },12000);

}, 24000); // <-- Don't run again until the full down/up cycle is complete
```

---

However, there are better ways to do this. First step in improving this is to use a callback for the `.animate` instead of `setTimeout`.

```
setInterval(function() {
    // Use a callback to schedule the "up" animation-------------------------v
    $(".scrollballer").animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 12000, function() {
       $('.scrollballer').animate({scrollTop:0}, 12000); 
    });

}, 24000);
```

---

Next step is to realize that the inner `.animate()` also can accept a callback, so we really don't need the `setInterval()`. The callbacks are better because JS timers aren't perfect, and one `.animate()` could start before the previous is finished. Using callbacks prevents this.

```
// -----------v---create a named function that performs the down/up animations
(function down_then_up() {

    $(".scrollballer").animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 12000, function() {

    // Use the `down_then_up` function as a callback----v--- to repeat the cycle
       $('.scrollballer').animate({scrollTop:0}, 12000, down_then_up); 
    });

})(); // <-- invoke the `down_then_up` immediately to get it going.
```

So here I make a function called `down_then_up` that performs the cycle of scrolling the page. The function is invoked immediately by the `()` at the very end. Then in the inner `.animate()` call that brings you back to the top, I pass the `down_then_up` function as the callback.

---

***EDIT***

Another issue is that when you're scrolling down, you're travelling the full window height, even though it's larger than the actual image container. So if the window height is `800`, jQuery calculates based on that number, so it thinks it needs to go a suitable speed to get there in 12 seconds.

However, on the way up, it starts from the current position *(which is actually only the container height)* and scrolls up to `0`, so now if the container height is `224`, jQuery calculates based on that number, meaning it needs to move more slowly to cover that shorter distance in 12 seconds.

If you set the distance to scroll based on the container height instead of the window, it'll calculate to move the same distance whether going up or down, and you'll get even speeds.

Comment: Thanks. Is it me, or it moves down a little faster ?
http://jsfiddle.net/gsmLrby2/

Comment: @user198989: I think the issue is that you're scrolling the full window height, which is beyond the size of the image container. So when it goes down, it has to move faster to make it the full distance in 12 seconds (even though it doesn't need to go all the way, jQuery doesn't know that). And when it goes up, it's going from the current position to `0`, so it's a shorter distance, meaning it'll move slower to get there. Instead, just scroll the container height of `224`. http://jsfiddle.net/gsmLrby2/1/